# validate md5 base64_encode to show value

Tags: php

I am comparing two `base64_encode md5` keys created with same values (IP,Time,Path & Password) on different domains.

Create Encrypted key on 1st domain

```
    $secret = "PASSWORD";
    $expires = time()+3600; 
    $uri = '/video1/';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $md5 = base64_encode(md5($secret . $expires . $uri . $ip, true)); 
    $md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_'); 
    $md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5); 
    $rtmp = "?md5=".$md5;
    $urls= 'http://example.com'.$uri .$rtmp;

    echo '<a href="' . $urls . '">' .$urls . '</a>';
```

Create Encrypted key on 2nd domain and compare with URL received Key

```
    function getAddress() {
        $protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
        return $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    $url = getAddress();
    $path = (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));    // recive path here '/video1/'
    $verify = substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY),4); //recive md5 encoded key from URL 

    /* create again md5 encoded key to match with URL key */
    $secret = "PASSWORD";
    $expires = time()+3600; 
    $uri = $path;
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $md5 = base64_encode(md5($secret . $expires . $uri . $ip, true)); 
    $md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_'); 
    $md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5); 
    $rtmp = $md5;

    if ($rtmp===$verify){     // Matching both, local key with URL key
        echo '<h1>Welcome</h1>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<h1>Password,Time,Path or IP Not Match</h1>';
    }
```

I used time(3600) in Encryption, So `if` statement should be show value for 3600 second. But this always show `else` value.

**How this will be print `if` value for time(3600)? After that time print `else`**

Comment: but you include time()+3600 in both md5 hash, so unless the 2 scripts executed at the exact same second, the 2 hash will be different... ?

Comment: Could you explain the purpose here - is it to time limit the url so that it is only valid for a certain length of time?

Comment: @RamRaider Yes, I want different URL each time and also work for certain length of time.

Comment: So 3600 seconds is the limit?

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé You right with every second they changed, is there any way this will be valid for 3600 second?

Comment: @Andreas Yes I am trying for 3600 time limit.

Comment: Why use MD5? It's not that safe anymore... Bcrypt is better...

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld doesn't matter since it's still passed in a a href link with GET. All safety is completely thrown out the window anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't copied all parts of your code but this is the principle.
Hash the password and time separate, that way you can make sure the password is correct and look at the time independently.

```
$secret = "PASSWORD";
$expires = time()+3600; 
$urls= 'http://example.com?md5=" . md5($secret) . "&t=" . md5($expires);
```

This will pass them independently and on the receiving end you match the password with password and you loop the time to see if it's valid.

```
if($_GET['md5'] == $password) $validM = true;

for($i = time()+3600; $i>time(); $i--){
    if(md5($i) == $_GET['t']) $validT = true;
 }

if($validM && $validT){
    echo "within 3600 seconds and correct password";
}
```

This is a safe method for about 95% of the world's population, but since we are passing password and time variables by GET, it's not that hard to figure out how to get illegal access.
**If it's something that needs safe transactions you are using this for then don't use this method.**

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps above and beyond the scope of the question but the whole `MD5` approach was flawed so why not go the "whole hog" ( as the saying goes ) and actually use encryption rather than hashing as in the question?

The `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions are based upon code found in the PHP manual for [openssl_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#example-977)

```
function encrypt( $data=false, $pubkey=false, $cipher='AES-128-CBC' ){
    if( !empty( $data ) && in_array( $cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods() ) ){
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length( $cipher );
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( $ivlen );

        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt( $data, $cipher, $pubkey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv );
        $hash = makehash( $encrypted, $pubkey );
        return base64_encode( $iv . $hash . $encrypted );
    }
    return false;
}
function decrypt( $data, $pubkey=false, $cipher='AES-128-CBC' ){
    if( !empty( $data ) && in_array( $cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods() ) ){
        $shalength=32;
        $data = base64_decode( $data );
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length( $cipher );
        $iv = substr( $data, 0, $ivlen );
        $hash = substr( $data, $ivlen, $shalength );

        $encrypted = substr( $data, $ivlen + $shalength );
        $decrypted = openssl_decrypt( $encrypted, $cipher, $pubkey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv );

        if( $decrypted && hash_equals( $hash, makehash( $encrypted, $pubkey ) ) ){
            return $decrypted;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function makehash( $data, $key ){
    return hash_hmac( 'sha256', $data, $key, true );
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
$lifetime=3600;
$key='A complex secret string - ideally this will be the contents of an ssl cert perhaps obtained using file_get_contents etc';
$cipher='AES-128-CBC';


/* Create the payload of items to be encrypted and passed in the url */
$payload=array(
    'endpoint'  =>  '/secret-forum/topic404',
    'expires'   =>  time() + $lifetime,
    'ip'        =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);
/* create a nice string to be encrypted */
$data=urldecode( http_build_query( $payload ) );

/* create the encrypted data string */
$encrypted=encrypt( $data, $key, $cipher );

/* construct the url to be presented to the user */
$url=sprintf( '%s://%s/?hash=%s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $encrypted );
printf('<a href="%1$s" target="_blank">%1$s</a>', $url);



/* At the Server - To process the url and check validity */
$querystring = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY );
if( !empty( $querystring ) ){

    list( $param, $data )=explode( '=', $querystring );

    /* decrypt data */
    $decrypted=decrypt( $data, $key, $cipher );
    if( $decrypted ){

        /* process initial querystring we created - create an array $out */
        parse_str( $decrypted, $out );

        /* for simplicity, cast as an object to use object notation */
        $obj=(object)$out;
        $endpoint=$obj->endpoint;
        $expires=$obj->expires;
        $ip=$obj->ip;




        /* perform logic tests on the decrypted data and act accordingly */
        if( time() > $expires or $ip!=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ){
            /* too late */
            printf( '<h1>That link has now expired</h1><p>You are no longer premitted to access that resource</p>' );
        } else {
            /* all good */
            printf( '<h1>Welcome</h1><p>%s</p>', $obj->endpoint );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It looks good. But have some issue on decrypted side, check link [LINK](http://skshost.com/post1/)

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @F.A if you need the manual on some function why not Google the function you need help with?

Comment: if the decryption is failing perhaps you need to urlencode the url before the user clicks the link and then urldecode serverside prior to decryption. The url: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#example-977